# NODE Is it bad practice to create a new Child Process.fork from close event of the Child Process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, child-process

I have a long running Node process that fully utilities a single thread therefore I migrated some `setInterval` tasks to a node child-process.

my child process is also long running and handles things like database updates and data validation.

I am still in the process of implementing proper error handling in the child-process and therefore I am closing the process on NetworkErrors or database errors and logging errors as I build.

**Is it bad practice to <s>recursively</s> recreate a child process from the `close` eventhandler?**

```
const cp = require('child_process');

const setupErrorProcess = () => {
    let errorCheck = cp.fork('./childProcess/errorCheck.js', { stdio: 'pipe' });

    errorCheck.on('close', (data) => {
        setTimeout(() => {setupErrorProcess()}, 1000) //close event is emitted once
    });

    errorCheck.on('message', (msg) => {
      console.log('Message from errorCheck', msg);
      //handle message here
    });
}

setupErrorProcess();
```

Comment: This seems fine. Are you worried about stack overflow? If so, I wouldn't worry--this isn't actually recursive.

Comment: @ggorlen ok thanks, I wanted to make sure the setTimeout will be enough to prevent an overflow (if network errors occur for >x seconds).

I also do not have any understanding on how garbage collection works so I want to make sure I protect myself against allocation errors. 

I am rethinking my architecture because my setIntervals stopped firing on time due to too many things going on.

Comment: Yeah, `setTimeout`/`setInterval` cannot be relied on for precise timing.

Comment: @ggorlen one of my tasks is to push state from memory to db every minute. parent process is web socket instance syncing with an external service receiving multiple messages per second. do you think creating a timer process to notify parent when it's time to pass data to child will solve my problem?

Comment: What's the point of having multiple processes? Can the "parent" (only) process not read the socket and write to the db? How critical is the timing here for db writes and socket reads?

Comment: @ggorlen initially that was the logic I had implemented. socket reads are critical db writes less important (trading data). I reconnect to socket if I miss a single sequence. I use json files that are updated every couple of seconds to hold backup as its the fastest way to boot < 1s. if something fails  (files missing/corrupted etc) I fallback to db < 2s and use an API to fill the missing gaps after socket reconnects. if the data fails to update for over a minute I am obligated to initialize exchange state by retrieving it through API. unfortunately the API is throttled and this takes me > 30s

Comment: My frontend relies on realtime data so my goal is to prevent system downtime. After every several hours my system is crashing so something else is wrong as well.